# Java Fib iterative and Fib recursive time comparison

Tags: java, recursion, time

Please if you could just check my work and help guide me through the System.currentTimeMillis() function. I understand that it takes a snapshot of my computer time and then when I end it it takes another snap shot and I use the difference of those times to get my run time. Just not sure I'm implementing it properly as my times for my iterative function and my recursive are almost always identical or at most 1 off. I'm confused a little as to if my start time is called again before my iterative starts or if really my time check for iterative time is iterative plus my recursive function. Should I have my total iterative time be endTimeIter - endTimeRecur? Any help is appreciated.

```
public class FibTest{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int n = 40;
        System.out.println("The 40th Fibonacci number per my recursive function is: " +    fibRecur(n));
           long endTimeRecur = System.currentTimeMillis();
           long totalTimeRecur = endTimeRecur - startTime;
        System.out.println("The 40th Fibonacci number per my recursive function is: " + fibIter(n));
           long endTimeIter = System.currentTimeMillis();
           long totalTimeIter = endTimeIter - startTime;
        System.out.println("The time it took to find Fib(40) with my recursive method was: " + totalTimeRecur);
        System.out.println("The time it took to find Fib(40) with my iterative method was: " + totalTimeIter);
    }
    public static int fibRecur(int n){
        if (n < 3) return 1;
        return fibRecur(n-2) + fibRecur(n-1);
    }
    public static int fibIter(int n){
        int fib1 = 1;
        int fib2 = 1;
        int i, result = 0;
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++ ){
            result = fib1 + fib2;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = result;
        }
        return result;
    }  
 }
```

Comment: I would avoid printing and calculating in the same line. I would probably make all the calculations first and print after that.

Comment: The reason I did it like this was my calculations after the print where to stop time, and since the print is my final call to my method I wanted to stop time and calculate it after I was done with both the recursive then the iterative Fib methods to capture the amount of time each function took to calculate the 40th Fib number.

Comment: I understand but you will gain precision by storing the 'stop time' in variables after the calculations, and then printing them. I would not trust the output stream in System.out to be without delay

Comment: but should I be getting around the exact same times for my recursive and iterative with my N=40? Or do I have it set up wrong regardless. If System.out did have delay it is still giving me that near identical result. 734 ms recurrsive and 735 ms iterative. Seems to consistant for me to believe it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

That's one way of how the time difference must be done

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
methodA();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

time = System.currentTimeMillis();
methodB();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Amir's answer:

One bug in your program is that you print

```
System.out.println("The 40th Fibonacci number per my recursive function is: " + fibIter(n));
```

I think what you want to say is:

```
System.out.println("The 40th Fibonacci number per my iterative function is: " + fibIter(n));
```

Comment: thank you, cutting and pasting my print line fail right there. I had caught it in my other println statement that i had cut and paste.